# How can i let users to write to each other in messenger from my website?

Tags: javascript, django, facebook, messenger

Im working in Django and i have a form in user profile for facebook account.
I want to integrate this to do something like down below but user to user not user to website.
[sth like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQxb7.png)

Comment: Hey Mwt_0239, welcome to Stack Overflow! This forum is about specific programming problems. Asking for "recommend[ations] or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.", as could be found in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (point 4). Please adjust your questions accordingly, or post it on another forum.

Comment: Welcome Mwt_0239 - this is a pretty broad question and much of it depends on if you are using a javascript front end or not. Searching on Google for "messenger app in django" will give you a few results with demo's using Angular, Vue and React as the front end with django supporting the logic. Once you've got some specific issue, this forum will be of the most value to you. Starting is hard, but the results from that search should give you some decent quality tutorials and demos.

Comment: There is no API to send user messages in Facebook messenger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want user to user chat then you can implement a chat server with [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)